# Duda para guardar un String en HashMap

Tags: java, object, lista, hashmap

Tengo un problemita..Es que estoy utilizando un HashMap> para guardar valores. Pero en determinados casos debo almacenar un String en vez de List.

Hay forma de hacer algun cast o algo por el estilo sin necesidad de que crear otro Map ?

Parte del codigo es el siguiente:

`HashMap<String,List<Object>> message = new HashMap<>();
 message.put("lista de juegos",user.getMyJuegos(IdPlayer));
 message.put("error","Please try again later");`

Donde user.getMyJuegos(IdPlayer) retorna un List con todos los juegos de un player. Y el mensaje de error es en caso de no encontrarse el player en la BD.
El problema se da en la linea del mensaje de error y es el siguiente: "no suitable method found for put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)"

Muchas Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para ayudarte a resolver un problema de este tipo, es necesario que expongas el código que has creado, aparte de explicar el problema. Es complicado ayudarte sin más detalles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes guardar directamente un string ya que la declaración del Map espera una lista, lo que tienes que hacer es tratar ese string como una lista más.
Solo inserta ese string en una nueva lista y guardalo así en el map:

```
message.put("error",Arrays.asList("Please try again later"));
```

Y para recuperar el valor, hazlo como con cualquier lista:

```
message.get("error").get(0);
```